# iText create document with unequal page sizes

Tags: java, android, pdf, itext, document

I want to create a pdf file using itext that has unequal page sizes. 
I have these two rectangles:

```
Rectangle one=new Rectangle(70,140);
 Rectangle two=new Rectangle(700,400);
```

and i am writing to the pdf like this :

```
Document document = new Document();
  PdfWriter writer=  PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(("MYpdf.pdf")));
```

when I create the document, I have the option to specify the page size , but I want different page sizes for different pages in my pdf. 
Is it possible to do that ?

Eg. The first page will have rectangle one as the page size, and the second page will have rectangle two as the page size.

Comment: `Document` has constructors accepting an initial page size. And the writer or the document have methods to set the page size for the next page.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've created an [UnequalPages](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/objects/UnequalPages) example for you that shows how it works:

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
Rectangle one = new Rectangle(70,140);
Rectangle two = new Rectangle(700,400);
document.setPageSize(one);
document.setMargins(2, 2, 2, 2);
document.open();
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Hi");
document.add(p);
document.setPageSize(two);
document.setMargins(20, 20, 20, 20);
document.newPage();
document.add(p);
document.close();
```

It is important to change the page size (and margins) *before* the page is initialized. The first page is initialized when you `open()` the document, all following pages are initialized when a `newPage()` occurs. A new page can be triggered explicitly (using the `newPage()` method in your code) or implicitly (by iText, when a page was full and a new page is needed).